# Php looped array into named variables

Tags: php, loops

I'm always having problems with arrays and loops and am completely stuck in this case:

Starting with this mysql query:

$sql = "select id, english from translate";

```
[
   {
      "detectedlanguage":{
         "language":"en",
         "score":1.0
      },
      "translations":[
         {
            "text":"[{\"id\":\"1\","0\":\"testiteksti täällä\",\"finnish\":\"testaa teksti täällä\"},{{\"id\":\"2\","0\":\"lisää testitekstiä täällä\",\"finnish\":\"lisää testitekstiä täällä\"},{{\"id\":\"3\","0\":\"ja lisää testitekstiä täällä\",\"finnish\":\"ja lisää testitekstiä täällä\"},{{\"id\":\"4\","0\":\"vielä lisää testitekstiä täällä\",\finnish\":\"vielä lisää testitekstiä täällä\"}]",
            "to":"fi"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I want to be able to take the id and translation and insert them into a database table. The following code returns the translation only, but I can't figure out how to get the id to appear as well and be used to update the database tables:

```
foreach($output as $x){ 
foreach($x->translations as $y){ 
$decoded = json_decode($y->text); 
foreach ($decoded as $z){ 
$insert = "update translate set finnish == '.((array)$z)[finnish].' where id =='.((array)$z)['0'].'"; 
}
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on how you store translations in the database?

Comment: database has id and original language version, which I then want to update the translated version in a different column, so id, english, finnish

Comment: I know how to get the 'text' value from the json, but that includes the ID value and the translation value. What I need to know is how to get the ID  and the translation values into separate variables to allow entry to the database